# "unknown error" when trying to edit widgets from Tooltwist Designer

Tags: tooltwist

I am using Tooltwist 8.3.1.

When trying to edit widget status from "Approved" to "Edit", I get an "unknown error" pop up.

Stacktrace :

**[INFO] 08:42:45.757 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR tooltwist.misc.ServletUiModule - Error in Servlet tooltwist.wbd.DesignerUIM.doPost():**

**[INFO] javax.servlet.ServletException: Error: com.dinaa.DinaaException: Error calling DesignerUIM.op_unlockWidget():**

**[INFO] tooltwist.wbd.WbdException: Trying to unlock widget in non web design project: mobile.product.selectorProductList**

[INFO]  at tooltwist.wbd.WbdLibrary.unlockWidget(WbdLibrary.java:2352) ~[ttWbd-8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:v8.0.0a1-146-g9c8e62e]

[INFO]  at tooltwist.wbd.DesignerUIM.op_unlockWidget(DesignerUIM.java:1886) ~[ttWbd-8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:v8.0.0a1-146-g9c8e62e]

[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]

[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]

[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]

[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]

[INFO]  at tooltwist.wbd.DesignerUIM.handler(DesignerUIM.java:237) ~[ttWbd-8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:v8.0.0a1-146-g9c8e62e]

[INFO]  at tooltwist.misc.AjaxUIM.appServletCode(AjaxUIM.java:373) ~[tooltwist-8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:v8.0.0a1-75-g926c781]

[INFO]  at tooltwist.misc.ServletUiModule.doPost_menuOption(ServletUiModule.java:3253) ~[tooltwist-8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:v8.0.0a1-75-g926c781]

[INFO]  at tooltwist.misc.ServletUiModule.doPost(ServletUiModule.java:2995) ~[tooltwist-8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:v8.0.0a1-75-g926c781]

[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]

[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]

[INFO]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]

[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]

[INFO] 08:42:45.757 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR tooltwist.misc.ServletUiModule - Root cause: null

[INFO] 08:42:45.757 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO  com.dinaa.ui.UiModule - UiModule.getAlternativeUrl(module=null, url=/tooltwist/basic/error.jsp)

[INFO] 08:42:45.757 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO  com.dinaa.ui.UiModule - UiModule.getAlternativeUrl(module=tooltwist.wbd.DesignerUIM, url=/tooltwist/basic/error.jsp)

[INFO] 08:42:45.758 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR com.dinaa.ui.UiModule - Exception in servlet tooltwist.wbd.DesignerUIM:

[INFO] javax.servlet.ServletException: Error: com.dinaa.DinaaException: Error calling DesignerUIM.op_unlockWidget():

[INFO] tooltwist.wbd.WbdException: Trying to unlock widget in non web design project: mobile.product.selectorProductList

[INFO]  at tooltwist.wbd.WbdLibrary.unlockWidget(WbdLibrary.java:2352) ~[ttWbd-8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:v8.0.0a1-146-g9c8e62e]

[INFO]  at tooltwist.wbd.DesignerUIM.op_unlockWidget(DesignerUIM.java:1886) ~[ttWbd-8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:v8.0.0a1-146-g9c8e62e]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your error StackTrace indicates the root of the problem:

**[INFO] tooltwist.wbd.WbdException: Trying to unlock widget in non web design project: mobile.product.selectorProductList**

You are trying to unlock a widget from your extension project which is the **mobile** project **(*mobile*.product.selectorProductList)**. These are the widgets found under **Widgets** section on your left tree navigation. Take notes that only webdesign assets (Page, Images, Zones, Frames, etc) has status and can be modified.